# Why do I have an error `Object is possibly 'null'` when fetching data in redux-thunk?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

So I'm using redux-thunk with redux toolkit, and I'm getting data with movies from the server.
My initial state looks like this:

```
const initialState: IPopularMoviesState = {
    popularMovie: null,
    fetchStatus: null,
    popularSearchPage: 1,
}
```

Interfaces:

```
export interface IPopularMoviesState {
  popularMovie: MovieResults | null;
  fetchStatus: FetchStatus | null;
  popularSearchPage: number;
}


export type MovieResults = {
    results: IMovie[],
};
```

Fetching thunk function:

```
export const fetchPopular = createAsyncThunk('popular/fetchPopular', async () => {
  const response = await fetchPopularMovies('popular');
  console.log(response.data);
  return response.data;
})
```

fetchPopularMovies() function:

```
export async function fetchPopularMovies(type:string) {
      let url: string = `${API_BASE}movie/${type}?api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}`;
      const response = await axios.get<MovieResults>(url);
      return response;
}
```

And finally my slice:

```
const popularSlice = createSlice({
  name:'popular',
  initialState,
  reducers:{},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchPopular.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.PENDING
      })
      .addCase(fetchPopular.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.SUCCESS
        // Add any fetched posts to the array
        state.popularMovie.results = state.popularMovie.results.concat(action.payload);
      })
      .addCase(fetchPopular.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.FAILURE
        
      })
  }
})
```

So as you see, it's all pretty basic, but I have a problem on that line:

```
.addCase(fetchPopular.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.SUCCESS
            // Add any fetched posts to the array
     //here typescript says that `state.popularMovie` object is possibly null
            state.popularMovie.results = state.popularMovie.results.concat(action.payload);

          })
```

So typescript says that `popularMovie` object is possible null, and it is in initial state, but I called a fetchPopular function in a component like this:

```
useEffect(() =>{
    if (postStatus === 'pending') {
      dispatch(fetchPopular())
    }
  }, [postStatus, dispatch])
```

So I'm not sure why it's being labeled as null, maybe there's some way to prevent it?